# Rearrange data files with inclusion of sequence numbers

Tags: python, file, output

I am in trouble trying to write a script to rearrange my file and hope that someone here can help. I browsed through stack overflow and found some nice script to solve my problem. Unfortunately, I still face some problems that need help.

Initially I have a file containing:

```
A X1 X2 X3
B X5 X6 X7
```

I want the file to be like this:

```
A, 1, X1
A, 2, X2
A, 3, X3
B, 1, X5
B, 2, X6
B, 3, X7
```

I try to code it like that but I do not know how to include the 1, 2, 3 in each rows like stated above:

```
with open('filename.txt','r') as f:
file=open('filename_2.txt','w')
for line in f:
    line=line.rstrip().split(' ')
    for item in line[1:]:
        p=line[0], item,'\n'
        file.writelines(p)
file.close()
```

Can someone teach me how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a handy built-in function called [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
for line in f:
    items = line.rstrip().split()
    for index, item in enumerate(items[1:]):
        file.write("{}, {}, {}\n".format(items[0], index, item)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help :) I read about the enumerate function and my problem is solved like magic!!!